# How to display public Visualforce page without salesforce logo

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I've set up [Salesforce Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312748&type=1&mode=1) on a scratch org and created a public Visualforce page AccountEdit. Tthe page displays with the Salesforce logo and the Account fields as read only.
[image]

The page has a custom controller (public,  no sharing) and inputField elements.

My question is two-fold:

1. How to display the public Visualforce page without salesforce logo and
2. How to achieve this without the [--c.visualforce.com](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312748&type=1&mode=1) format URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to display the public Visualforce page without salesforce logo

In your page, use `<apex:page showHeader="false" ...`

> How to achieve this without the --c.visualforce.com format URL?

Follow the directions to [Configure a Custom Domain for Your Experience Cloud Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_domain.htm&type=0). Note that you must have your own domain or subdomain that you control in order to do this. Various services out there offer a variety of domain names from free to hundreds of dollars a year. It all depends on how much you want to invest.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know why the inputFields show as read only without the --c.visualforce.com format URL? The other issue I have with --c.visualforce.com is that it requires log in.

Comment: It's showing because guest user may have read only permission in the profile.

Comment: @T.Webster visualforce.com is for internal access. You want to use the force.com or site.com address found in Setup/Develop/Sites.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've found a reason why the inputFields were read only - because the Account on the page was queried. If instead we let the Account  be `new Account()` then the fields are read/write.

Comment: @T.Webster That's a sharing problem, then. You may need to tweak your sharing rules.